# Ruby on Rails form_for local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change a variable on a controller when a button in the view is clicked. 
my function in the controller:

```
   def show   

    @choiceV = true 

    if params[:changeviewbutton]
      @choiceV= !@choiceV      
    end       

  end
```

and in my view:

```
   <%= form_for @choiceV do %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Change view', :name => 'changeviewbutton'%>
    <% end %>
```

The error I get is:

```
    undefined method `model_name' for true:TrueClass
```

Does form_for functions only with models?
or it works also with local variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form_for is for an instance of a model. The form_tag is what you are looking for. You can read more about both these helpers in the api docs - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for